# Jest - test an async default export

Tags: node.js, promise, jestjs

Suppose I have `my-file.ts`:

```js
async function run() {

  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 3000);
  });

  setTimeout(() => console.log('hello'), 5000);

}

export default run();
```

And I want to test it with Jest. If I do:

```js
it('should wait until all code has executed', async () => {
  const start = new Date();
  console.log('Waiting...', new Date());

  await require('./my-file').default;

  const stop = new Date();
  console.log(`done after ${(stop.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000} s`);
});
```

The result is:

```
  console.log test/tmp.test.ts:3
    Waiting... 2020-01-03T11:56:59.822Z

  console.log test/tmp.test.ts:8
    done after 3.009 s
```

This makes sense. But when I compile and run `my-file.ts`, node waits for all timeouts to have cleared, and all console logs are properly displayed:

```sh
$ tsc my-file.ts && node my-file.js
hello
$
```

I want to reproduce the behavior of Node, which is to wait for all async code to be executed. How can I do this with jest ?

Also, can anyone explain why the following does not wait at all ?

```js
it('should wait until all code has executed', async () => {
  await require('./my-file');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Promise `resolves` after 3sec and the test from jest gets run, because you block execution with `await require('./my-file').default;` until the Promise is `resolved` or `rejected`. Your second timeout just adds a timeout callback to the event queue after 5 sec that will run.

To replicate waiting for 5 sec resolve the Promise in the second timeout. Also you don't need `async/await` if you return a new promise.

```
function run() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => console.log('hello after 3 sec'), 3000);
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000);
    });
}

export default run();
```